# Javascript function in phtml files

Tags: magento2, javascript, customer, jquery

I am using onclick function in my template file, 
here is my html

```
 <div class="input-box">
            <input type="checkbox" name="change_password" id="change_password" value="1" onclick="setPasswordForm(this.checked)" title="<?php echo 'Change Password'; ?>"<?php if($_user->getChangePassword()==1): ?> checked="checked"<?php endif; ?> class="checkbox" />
        </div>
```

Below is my javascript code

```
<script>
 require([
     'jquery',
     'mage/mage'
  ], function($){
 function setPasswordForm(arg){
    if(arg){
        $('current_password').up(4).show();
        $('current_password').addClassName('required-entry');
        $('password').addClassName('required-entry');
        $('confirmation').addClassName('required-entry');

    }else{
        $('current_password').up(4).hide();
        $('current_password').removeClassName('required-entry');
        $('password').removeClassName('required-entry');
        $('confirmation').removeClassName('required-entry');
    }
}
<?php if($_user->getChangePassword()): ?>
    setPasswordForm(true);
<?php endif; ?>

});

</script>
```

How to use it in magento2? It is working fine in m1.

I am getting below error when used above code

Uncaught ReferenceError: setPasswordForm is not defined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the below code for html(Remove the onclick):

```
<div class="input-box"> 
<input type="checkbox" name="change_password" id="change_password" value="1" title="<?php echo 'Change Password'; ?>" class="checkbox" /> 
</div>
```

and use the following javascript:

```
<script>
require(['jquery'], function($){
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#change_password').click(function(){
            if($(this).is(':checked')){
                $('current_password').up(4).show();
                $('current_password').addClassName('required-entry');
                $('password').addClassName('required-entry');
                $('confirmation').addClassName('required-entry');
            }
            else{
                $('current_password').up(4).hide();
                $('current_password').removeClassName('required-entry');
                $('password').removeClassName('required-entry');
                $('confirmation').removeClassName('required-entry');
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: No, getting same error again, cleared cache also

Comment: Whats is the error?

Comment: Same like previous one 
Uncaught ReferenceError: setPasswordForm is not defined

What is difference in your code ? it also looks like my code.

Comment: No I have removed the mage. The code I pasted is working fine in my local system. I have added that code to my addtocart.phtml.

Comment: Please share me html code, for me it is not working

Comment: Check my updated answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81277/discussion-between-jafar-and-sukumar-gorai).

Answer (score 3):

Main error in question is,
You have declared a new function inside

```
function($){
}
```

You can not call function declared inside `function($) {}` anywhere outside of it.

One trick is to declare function variable before `function($) {}` and then define it inside jQuery function code as below.

```
<script>
var foo;                           // Here's the difference
require(['jquery'], function($){
  foo = function ()
  {
    alert('Bar');
  }
});
</script>
```

Reference :
[Can not define function inside jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1055767/why-can-i-not-define-functions-in-jquerys-document-ready)

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
requirejs(['jquery'], function (jQuery) {
    jQuery(function ($) {
function setPasswordForm(arg){ console.log('test')
    if(arg){
        $('current_password').up(4).show();
        $('current_password').addClassName('required-entry');
        $('password').addClassName('required-entry');
        $('confirmation').addClassName('required-entry');

    }else{
        $('current_password').up(4).hide();
        $('current_password').removeClassName('required-entry');
        $('password').removeClassName('required-entry');
        $('confirmation').removeClassName('required-entry');
    }
}
<?php if($_user->getChangePassword()): ?>
    setPasswordForm(true);
<?php endif; ?>
   });
});

</script>
```

use `reequirejs` instead of `require` as given , clear static-content and cache , this may work

Comment: Its Not working